# TypeScript function overloading with enum

Tags: typescript, enums, overloading

I'm running into a little issue when trying to implement function overloading with TypeScript in conjunction with an enum being passed as a parameter, and a second argument whose type depends on the enum.

For example:

- If the enum is `FOO`, then the second argument is of a `string` type
- If the enum is `BAR`, then the second argument is of a `number` type
- If the enum is `BAZ`, there is no second argument

The code I have is as follow, but somehow TypeScript throws an error because even when I'm checking the first argument against the enum, intellisense does not narrow down the type of the second argument: `fieldValue` is always `string | number`.

```
enum ViewName {
    FOO = 'foo',
    BAR = 'bar',
    BAZ = 'baz'
}

function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.FOO, stringValue: string);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAR, numberValue: number);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAZ);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName, fieldValue?: string | number): void {

    if (viewName === ViewName.FOO) {
        fieldValue = fieldValue.reverse();
    }

    if (viewName === ViewName.BAR) {
        fieldValue *= 2;
    }

    if (viewName === ViewName.BAZ) {
        return console.log('No fieldvalue is supplied by BAZ.');
    }

    console.log(fieldValue);
}
```

The code can also be viewed on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20ViewName%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FOO%20%3D%20'foo'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BAR%20%3D%20'bar'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20BAZ%20%3D%20'baz'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction(viewName%3A%20ViewName.FOO%2C%20stringValue%3A%20string)%3B%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction(viewName%3A%20ViewName.BAR%2C%20numberValue%3A%20number)%3B%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction(viewName%3A%20ViewName.BAZ)%3B%0D%0Afunction%20myFunction(viewName%3A%20ViewName%2C%20fieldValue%3F%3A%20string%20%7C%20number)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(viewName%20%3D%3D%3D%20ViewName.FOO)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldValue%20%3D%20fieldValue.reverse()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(viewName%20%3D%3D%3D%20ViewName.BAR)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fieldValue%20*%3D%202%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(viewName%20%3D%3D%3D%20ViewName.BAZ)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20console.log('No%20fieldvalue%20is%20supplied%20by%20BAZ.')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(fieldValue)%3B%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I think overloads are only for *callers* of the function; inside, it's just the last definition you provided.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're correct: it seems like function overloads work when you're calling them (so that one can have specific combinations of arguments), but this narrowing of type is not passed into the function itself :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Typescript will not narrow the type of the second parameter based on the type of the first parameter. This feature is just not implemented in typescript.

You can either add extra checks to the `if` to let the compiler narrow the type of `fieldValue`

```
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.FOO, stringValue: string);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAR, numberValue: number);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAZ);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName, fieldValue?: string | number): void {

    if (viewName === ViewName.FOO && typeof fieldValue === "string") {
        fieldValue = fieldValue.reverse();
    }
    else if (viewName === ViewName.BAR && typeof fieldValue === 'number') {
        fieldValue *= 2;
    }

    console.log(fieldValue);
}
```

Or you can just use a type assertion:

```
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.FOO, stringValue: string);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAR, numberValue: number);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName.BAZ);
function myFunction(viewName: ViewName, fieldValue?: string | number): void {

    if (viewName === ViewName.FOO) {
        fieldValue = (fieldValue as string).reverse();
    }
    else if (viewName === ViewName.BAR) {
        fieldValue =  (fieldValue as number) * 2;
    }

    console.log(fieldValue);
}
```

A bigger change would be to use a discriminated union, that will allow the compiler to narrow the type of the parameter in a more expected way:

```
function myFunction(p: { viewName: ViewName.BAZ }
    | { viewName: ViewName.BAR, fieldValue: number }
    | { viewName: ViewName.FOO, fieldValue: string }): void {

    if (p.viewName === ViewName.FOO) {
        p.fieldValue =  p.fieldValue.reverse();
    }
    else if (p.viewName === ViewName.BAR) {
        p.fieldValue *=  2;
    }

    console.log(fieldValue);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer my question: I didn't know that TypeScript cannot infer/narrow the type of other parameters based on function overloads. That cleared up my doubts :)

Comment: @Terry what did you end up doing for your case?

Comment: @James111 I couldn’t remember since it’s a piece of old code, but if I’m going to do it today again after a few years of working with typescript I’d go for the last suggestion, ie discriminated union.